# What is the difference between "He talks in a confident way" and "He talks confidently"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, adverbs

Later statement seems concise and commonly used. Do both of these sentences necessarily means the same thing?

Answer (score -1):

When you turn an adjective into an adverb, this is usually done by adding "-ly". He is clever. He talks cleverly. He is confident. He talks confidently.

For long adjectives, this will create an overly long adverb. He is inconsiderate. He speaks inconsiderately? No, that word is just too long, so in this case we say "He speaks in an inconsiderate way".

"Confident" is a borderline case. You can use "He speaks confidently", and "He speaks in a confident way", and both mean the same.